# Angular Dropdown ng-selected passing undefined

Tags: angularjs

I am calling a setProductId function in controller but when the parameter reaches the function in the controller the parameter is undefined.

```
<div class="form-group">  
   <label class="control-label" >New Dropdown</label>                          
   <select>
     data-ng-model="engineer.currentActivity"
     data-ng-options="c.name for c in sampleProductCategories[0].products"
     ng-selected="setProductId(c)"
   </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div class="form-group">  
 <label class="control-label" >New Dropdown</label>                          
 <select
  data-ng-model="engineer.currentActivity"
  data-ng-options="c.name for c in sampleProductCategories[0].products"
  ng-selected="setProductId(engineer.currentActivity)">
 </select>
</div>
```

You forgot to include the attributes inside select tag.

Comment: that looks typo by OP

Comment: thank you. i fixed the typo but still get the same results.  the setProducts call get an undefined passed to it.

Comment: in other words the c object is not defined, i'm missing something like this.c or something else?

Comment: can you create a fiddle?

Comment: if c is not defined then there is some problem with sampleProductCategories[0].products
What is the content of sampleProductCategories[0].products?

Comment: this is the object that is supposed to be passed in as a parameter{ productid = Object {name: "Pay", processor: " ", boarding_id: 25, productName: "4", $$hashKey: "02Z" }

Comment: You will have to pass the model in ng-selected directive. Editing my answer.